# NSDateFormater with leading zero

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to get day, minute and seconds with leading zero?

```
NSDateFormatter *lDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[lDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LL-d-yyyy-H-m-s"];  
NSString *lTime = [lDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
// Output : 04-3-2013-14-4-1
```

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

Comment: Thank you for the URL. It worked after clean build. –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the date specifier twice: `LL-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss`

```
NSDateFormatter *lDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[lDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LL-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss"];
NSString *lTime = [lDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", lTime);
```

Will output: `Date: 04-15-2013-12-04-51`

Comment: Not working 04-3-2013-14-3-58

Comment: I am using [lDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: If have just checked my code, it will produce the correct output.

Comment: Thank you. it worked after clean build.

Answer (score 2):

use the `MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss` format